# How to prove in K $ \vdash_{p \rightarrow \lozenge \square p} (\square p \rightarrow \lozenge p)$?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

Let us denote $C$ the modal system obtained by adding the axiom $ \alpha \rightarrow \lozenge \square \alpha$ to the axiom $K$ and all the propositional tautologies.

As said in the title, I'm looking for a K-proof for $$ \vdash_C (\square p \rightarrow \lozenge p),$$ but also for 
$$\vdash_C (\lozenge p \rightarrow \square p).$$

I know these proofs should exist since a Kripke frame verifies  the formula $p \rightarrow \lozenge \square p$ if and only if it verifies $$ (1) \ \ \forall x ( \exists y : (x \mathrel{R} y) \text{ and } (y \mathrel{R} z \Rightarrow z = x) ).$$

It particular $(1)$ implies that the frame is serial ( i.e. $\forall x (\exists y : x \mathrel{R} y)$), that is $ \square p \rightarrow \lozenge p$ is true, and that the frame is functional ( i.e. ($x \mathrel{R} y \text{ and } x \mathrel{R} z) \Rightarrow y =z$), that is $\lozenge p \rightarrow \square p$ is true.

Thank you for any answer !

Answer (score 2):

(For the first): Consider the set up where $\neg p$ holds at the actual world and where no world is accessible from that world. Then the  lhs of your sequent evaluates as true, and the right false ... (since $\Box p$ is vacuously true, and $\Diamond p$ is false).

(For the second): Consider the two-world set-up where in the actual self-accessible world $\neg p$, and there is one other accessible world where $p$. The lhs of your sequent evaluates as true, and the right false ...

So something is amiss there? Neither is a valid K-sequent so neither is K-provable.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think we can't deduct $p$ from $\square p$ unless we are working with reflexive Kripke frames, which is not the case in general.

Comment: Oops, getting my K's and T's entangled!

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that your counter-example won't resist a substitution since $\neg p \rightarrow \lozenge \square \neg p$ is not valid in your set up.

I know the implications are true, I'm just looking for a proof.

Comment: But I've given you, in each case, a K-model where the l.h. wff is true and the r.h. wff false. So (by soundness for the K proof system) the l.h. doesn't K-prove the r.h. wff. The implications aren't true.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry but I must disagree. For instance, take the model with one world and an empty relation, by substituing $p$ by $\neg p$, we obtain $ (p \rightarrow \lozenge \square p) \vdash_K (\neg p \rightarrow \lozenge \square \neg p)$. While I totaly agree that in your example $p \rightarrow \lozenge \square p$ is true in the world considered (because $p$ is false), the formula $ \neg p \rightarrow \lozenge \square \neg p$ is false (because the world does not see anyone). I think you confuse validity as model (that is for a given valuation) and validity as frame (for all valuations).

Comment: Agree on nomenclature of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics  Then K is sound w.r.t. the inferences valid in every K frame, so in particular if $\alpha \vdash_K \beta$, then given any K frame, and any valuation of the relevant atoms in that frame, if  $\alpha$ comes out true, so does $\beta$. So it suffices to refute  $\alpha \vdash_K \beta$ to find one K frame and one valuation on that frame which makes  $\alpha$ true and $\beta$ false. No?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Because if what you're saying is true, then we should have $(p\rightarrow \lozenge \square p) \not\vdash_K (\neg p \rightarrow \lozenge \square \neg p)$ (and we know it's false because of substitution). Indeed, using your example, we have a frame and a valuation on it  where the l.h. formula is true and the r.h. one is false, as said previously. We then have something absurd. What is true however is that $ \alpha \not \vdash_K \beta$ if and only if we find a frame where $\alpha$ is true for all valuations and a valuation on this frame such that $\beta$ is false.

Comment: I wonder if, for a start, you are confusing $\alpha \vdash \beta$ and if $\vdash \alpha$ then $\vdash \beta$ ...

Comment: To be honest, I was wondering exactly the same about you. Because I totally agree that $\not \vdash_K (p \rightarrow \lozenge \square p) \rightarrow (\square p \rightarrow \lozenge p)$ as you proved it. Let's say that when I write $\alpha \vdash_K \beta$, I intend that $\alpha$ is a new axiom added to tautologies and K.

Comment: Ahah. That is surely not the default usage of an otherwise uncommented syntactic turnstile? But this at least explains why we have been talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: Well, I'm happy we found the problem :). But now, the question is, how should I write my question correctly ?

Comment: I'd have said "Let C be the modal system you get by adding to K all axioms of the form $\alpha \to \Diamond\Box\alpha$. Then how do we show $\vdash_C \Box p \to \Diamond p$, etc." [I've plucked the label "C" out of the air -- I don't know off-hand if there is a label already in use.]

Comment: The text is updated, thank you for your help.